# Error upon opening form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am going crazy with the easiest piece of code that just won't work. I can't fugure out why. I have a button on a form that opens another form but when i click it I get the following error and don't really know what to change:

[image]

my code click code is:

```
Private Sub HSbrowse_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSearchPCR"

End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: look at the list of references in the database and on that particular form. It could be that one or more libraries has become unregistered on the system.

Comment: The error does not occur when i manually open the form and yes it compile with option explicit. It's driving me crazy. Both forms aren't linked to any table. they both only contain buttons. I commented out any other button code and still nothing.

Comment: actually I jut changed the code to MsgBox "hello" and still same error. The error must have to do with the current form since it occurs before the code even runs.

Comment: Try building a new, empty database and import all your objects from the one in question. Then set any references that are needed and see what happens. It might be a corrupt file.

Comment: Quick search pointed to : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907337

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue several times. I believe that it is caused by the module of your form becoming corrupt. To fix it, set the "Has Module" property of your form to "No" and save and close your form. This will delete the module and any code it contains, so you will need to copy your code first. Open the VBA window to verify that the module was deleted, then reopen your form and set its "Has Module" property back to "Yes" and paste your code back in. This method has solved this problem for me on more than one occasion.

Comment: This answer fixed this problem for me. I would recommend editing it to give the warning about backing up the code up front - users who simply follow the instructions line by line might not think to do that until it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

Does the current form has any ActiveX Control in it?

If not then your form may be corrupt, 
rebuild your database using e.g. TM-RebuildDatabase

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing individual controls one-at-a-time. When your error goes away you will know the offending control, if that is indeed the problem.

Does the form have underlying data? Did you remove that to see if the problem changes?